# Meaning of ISUPPZ in LAPACK's DSYEVR

Tags: lapack

I want to calculate the eigensystem to some large real symmetric matrices and found the routine [DSYEVR](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d3b/dsyevr_8f.html) should suit my needs.

```
dsyevr (JOBZ, RANGE, UPLO, N, A, LDA, VL, VU, IL, IU, ABSTOL, M, W, Z, LDZ, ISUPPZ, WORK, LWORK, IWORK, LIWORK, INFO)
```

While including and testing this routine, I noticed the parameter `isuppz` which is an integer array of length `2*m`, where `m` specifies the number of calculated eigenvalues (which might change depending on the input data).

According to the documentation, the array `isuppz` specifies the position of non-zero elements in the array of eigenvectors `z`. I.e. in particular, the `i`th eigenvector has non-zero elements between positions `isuppz(2*i-1)` and `isuppz(2*i)`.

Now, I have the problem, that this doesn't really match my observations. E.g. while calculating the eigensystem to an example system of size `N=400`, the second eigenvector has, according to `isuppz`, only non-zero elements between positions `349` and `400`. Looking at the eigenvector, I can see, that this is clearly not the case, and comparing with `Mathematica`, I can clearly see, that this shouldn't be the case, too.

Actually, the eigensystem from `DSYEVR` is in principle the same as the eigensystem calculated by `Mathematica`. As a result, I assume that there is nothing wrong in general.

So, what is the actual meaning of the parameter `isuppz`?